# Cordova's APP_SECRET discovered in config.xml file

Tags: mobile

What is the security implication of the APP_SECRET being discovered in a Cordova Mobile app? Steps on how to get the APP_SECRET is described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/cordova) but there appears to be no clear guidance on what the risk is if it gets exposed.

I am looking at a number of Cordova mobile apps at the moment, and almost every single one of them appears to have the APP_SECRET hard-coded in the Cordova config.xml file. Is this a major risk? Or it is just a unique ID for Microsoft to be able to report analytics data back to the App Centre for the developer to review - so it is not a significant security risk, if exposed?

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking at a number of Cordova mobile apps at the moment, and
>   almost every single one of them appears to have the APP_SECRET
>   hard-coded in the Cordova config.xml file. Is this a major risk?

Microsoft does not consider it a major risk (neither do I), since the APP_SECRET value is used to map the app to an user account in App Center, and the App Center itself is only used for reporting of Analytics, Crashes and Push Notifications.

Configuring the APP_SECRET value in the `config.xml` is a Microsoft requirement. From the [App Center SDK for Apache Cordova GitHub page](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-cordova):

> To get it working in your app you will need to add some configuration
>   values to your app configuration in `config.xml` file. See list of
>   available parameters below
>
> - APP_SECRET - (*required*) App secret which enables App Center to map this app to the right user account

A threat model would better define the risk and impact of this scenario, and with the Microsoft official documentation confirming this is the correct setup, and knowing the App Center does not handle sensitive or critical information for the app, one can argue having the APP_SECRET value in the `config.xml` file, portrays a low risk with a low impact.

Comment: Thanks for your succinct answer - much appreciated.